# Как работать на Java в Visual studio code или community

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

У меня visual studio code последней версии(скачал в 2020)
Незнаю как писать консольные программы на java с помощью visual studio code. С Visual studio community тоже самое.

Comment: Так VS Code или VS?

Comment: Берите `NetBeans`, и не парьтесь.

Answer (score 1):

Есть хорошая инструкция для VSC - [на их же (VSC) сайте](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java).
Лично я пробовал, мне не очень понравилось. Это скорее вариант для тех, кто уже привык к VSC и кому неудобно переключаться на Eclipse или IntelliJ. Но вы можете попробовать.
Про поддержку разработки на Java в VS community мне не известно.

Answer (score 0):

Ни как. Данные среды разработки не предназначены для разработки на языке Java.
Используйте например IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

Писать приложения на Java вполне себе можно на Visual Studio Code (это редактор кода). Достаточно поставить необходимые расширения. Затем, можно запускать, и можно отлаживать проекты, в том числе и со сборщиком, типа Maven.

А, Visual Studio (Community) это IDE, она не предназначена для написания кода на Java.

Answer (score 0):

UPD:  Появилась возможность кодить и visual studio code
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java

Тут: упоминалось об этом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1089661/1365

Comment: Почему именно с января 2022? В [одном из ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1089661/1365) (данном 2 марта 2020) дана точно такая же ссылка

Comment: Исправил, думал что с 2022 появилась возможность, сам в Idea работаю, просто новость попалось недавно)

Comment: "Тут: упоминалось об этом" - это ответ под этим же вопросом. Фактически ваш ответ просто дублирует информацию оттуда.